# How do I outtput Azure cognitive services Text to speech (TTS) to MP3 file? Keep getting

Tags: php, curl, mp3, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Azure Cognitive Services with text to speech (tts) in combination with PHP and Curl and while I am getting output, I am not getting anything usable as I need an MP3 file as an output.

Here is my code:

```
$token = getAccessToken();

////$token=getToken();
$cont='<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice name="en-US-ChristopherNeural">
        
            Testing testing 123
        
    </voice>
</speak>';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($cont));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/ssml+xml';
$headers[] = 'Host: eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen($cont);
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;//Token okay
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: EasternServer';
$headers[] = 'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: raw-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $result;
```

Comment: SOLVED: Needed to take the raw output stream and save it as .mp3 file on server.

Comment: As the issue was resolved, consider posting the solution as an answer, so the similar issues can be solved with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the OP that the issue has been resolved.

(Posting the findings as an answer so that if someone faced the similar issue in future, he would get the solution on this thread. This will be helpful for other community contributors)

The issue has been resolved when the raw output stream in text to speech conversion has been saved as a `.mp3` file extension at the destination.